# How to implement a timer with interruption in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, timer, interrupt

I'm using the GCC compiler and C++ and I want to make a timer that triggers an interruption when the countdown is 0.

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Adam, I know how to do it.

Now. What about multiple timers running in parallel?

Actually, these timers are for something very basic. In NCURSES, I have a list of things. When I press a key, one of the things will change colors for 5 seconds. If I press another key, another thing in the list will do the same. It's like emphasize strings depending on the user input. Is there a simpler way to do that?

Comment: That's nowhere near enough information about the application.  Is it a command-line application, graphical, background network service, or what?  Does it already have a main event loop?  Does it use some framework for that?

Comment: The program is using ncurses interface. And yes, it has a main event loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the [`alarm(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) system call to send a `SIGALRM` to your process when the timer runs out:

```
void sigalrm_handler(int sig)
{
    // This gets called when the timer runs out.  Try not to do too much here;
    // the recommended practice is to set a flag (of type sig_atomic_t), and have
    // code elsewhere check that flag (e.g. in the main loop of your program)
}

...

signal(SIGALRM, &sigalrm_handler);  // set a signal handler
alarm(10);  // set an alarm for 10 seconds from now
```

Take careful note of the cautions in the man page of `alarm`:

> **alarm()** and **setitimer()** share the same timer; calls to one will interfere with use of the other.
>
> **sleep()** may be implemented using **SIGALRM**; mixing calls to **alarm()** and **sleep()** is a bad idea.
>
> Scheduling delays can, as ever, cause the execution of the process to be delayed by an arbitrary amount of time.

Answer (score 4):

An easy, portable way to implement an interrupt timer is using [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).  Specifically, the [boost::asio::deadline_timer class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html) allows you to specify a time duration and an interrupt handler which will be executed asynchronously when the timer runs out.

See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html) for a quick tutorial and demonstration.