# C++ Timer Run on Main Thead Without Block (C++11/14/17/20)

Tags: c++, c++11

How to implement a timer run on main thread without block main thread in C++11/14/17/20

Like:

```
  startTimerInCurrentTheadWithoutBlockCurrentThread(Seconds(1),[](){
//invoke method every 1 second
       method();
   });
```

I know there are a lot project like:https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/28/timer-cpp/

but they all start a new thread.

Comment: There's a reason why all available libraries/projects launch the timer in new thread. That's because if you don't, then your main method will be blocked by the timer method. You surely don't want your program to just keep counting and not do any actual processing.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. C is inappropriate here, because lambda. C++11,14,17 and 17 are unnecessary.

Comment: Just about any question starting with "can we do..." (or similar) could be answered with "yes". Please try to elaborate on your problems, and [edit] your question to improve it. Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @DebarghaRoy In iOS, Android, We hava a runloop in main thread.  The thread is alive until the app be killed.  So I want to  have a timer in this main thread.

Comment: For some self-promotion, please see [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865460/issue-when-scheduling-tasks-using-clock-function/11866539#11866539).

Comment: In Linux, you can use `alarm` and `SIGALRM` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4001261/580083). But not sure about Android or iOS. Anyway, it's not pure C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i liket your self-promotion :) today you can use `boost::asio::deadline_timer` no?

Answer (score 1):

There's three main approaches you can take to waiting an amount of time:

- blocking the main thread
- having a thread do the waiting
- having your main thread poll the clock regularly

You seem to not want the first two approaches. That would only leave you with the approach of letting the main thread run, saving the start time somewhere, and calling very regularly a function: `IsItTimeToCallMyFunction()`, say in a main loop.

It would be very inelegant and it would still open you to having the function not called soon enough, if something lengthy happens in your main thread.

So, in practice, your answer is "no".
Edit: The question was changed to "how", so the answer becomes "by using one of the three approaches above".

Answer (score 0):

Say, you want *concurrency*, yet you do not want a *thread*. You also do not want to *block* the main thread.

Then the answer is much more than clear. You want **coroutine + manual management of time slices**.

I don't think it a brilliant idea to manually operate between two concurrent tasks. So I recommend you learn something about coroutines. C++ is merging it into the standard but that is still not fully supported by every main-stream compilers or libraries. You could resort to some third-party library for that.

However, why not use a thread anyway?

EDIT:

Sorry that I did not read carefully. Now I think what you want is a timer to "interrupt" your current task - that is, to alarm you when the specified time has passed away.

Maybe you would like to investigate into "software interrupt"? As far as I know, the most straight way is to provide an exception handler to the system and trigger the interrupt when the time's out.

Comment: In iOS, Android, We hava a runloop in main thread. The thread is alive until the app be killed. So I want to have a timer in this main thread.  I want to call a Java native method in android main UI thread, then the c++ invoke a timer to do something on this main thread  without block the UI thread. Thanks.

Comment: @Learing Oh, I think you may want to query whether it is time to call back to the timer in the end of every loop. I don't think it will take up too much time

Comment: Sounds like you need an event loop then.